# Form_Shown and mouse click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have c# code which moves and clicks mouse, i must press button on form to start code, but i need that my code would start himself, not when button is pressed i tried to achieve this with formshown. It shows form but dont start the code. Its just a bit of code:

```
 private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        RightClick(28, 132);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        LeftClick(35, 137);
    }
```

Any ideas how my form could start doing things after it is opened?

Every time i open my windowsform application i have to press start button and after that my mouse starts clicking coordinates. I want that mouse would start moving without me clicking button its like autostart or something i dont know how to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Call your code on Form Load Event

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        RightClick(28, 132);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        LeftClick(35, 137);

    }
```

you can also call your code into constructor but it would be better if you call it inside `form_load event`

```
public yourform()
{ 
       Thread.Sleep(5000);
        RightClick(28, 132);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        LeftClick(35, 137);
}
```

Comment: form loads but doesnt do anything

Comment: @D3canas add more details to your question so that we can answer you what you are looking for

Comment: put a debug point on form load event and check what is going wrong with your code

Comment: there is no errors in code everything works fine then all code is in click_button event

Comment: i tried to add simple hello message in load event and it didnt showed